# Recieve notification when specific device connects to router

Tags: router

I am wondering if anyone knows a way for a router to output a notification (email or push or API call) when a specific device connects.

I am hoping to tie this in with IFTTT for use as presence detection with smartthings. Currently I can do this from the device side with Android or iOS, but that only works if IFTTT is installed on the phone with an active account. If I could do it from the router side I could trigger guest modes based on recurring guest MAC connections without having to install any software on the device.

Would preferably like to be able to use the IFTTT maker channel to trigger the event, but an email or push notification could work too.

Comment: I found a way to do this directly to smartthings but I am going to leave the question open for more options. https://community.smartthings.com/t/presence-detection-using-dd-wrt-router-script/13731

Answer (score 0):

I find very difficult to find a router that notifies you whenever there is a new connection.

However you can set a script on a linux device ([raspberry pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/), for example) using `nmap` to detect new devices on your network.

The script runs periodically and if it detects a new IP address on the network then it can send an email or notification to the *Maker channel* on IFTTT.

Check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398321/notification-when-someone-connects-to-my-local-network-arp-notification-file) on askubuntu.com; in the answer there is a simple bash script that you can expand with the features that you need.

Comment: might be easier to check the ARP table for the MAC address of target device, and use that as a trigger.   If it's a router, it should show up there either due to traffic, or things like DHCP.   You'd probably need to periodically ping it to detect when it disconnected, or it might get pushed out of ARP and then come back when it wakes up, loking the same as a new insertion